# how get curent URL slug from archive page

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using **woocommerce multi vendor plugin**, this is my current URL

```
http://localhost/cloudstock4/vendor/vender-two/
```

I want to get this last couple of word. i think this page use the WP archive.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to get what you want in the query made with the request.

```
$vendor = get_query_var('vendor');
```

If the vendor var is set, $vendor will be 'vender-two'.

Hope it helps

Comment: 'vendor' is page i created. there is vendors shortcode. i want to write code in functions.php

Comment: So you need to add the query Var by yourself with add_query_var()

Comment: I'm new to wordpress. can you give me example please..

Comment: function hitcount(){

 global $wpdb;
 global $wp_query;

 $user = wp_get_current_user();

 $curntUser = $wp_query->queried_object ;

 $wpdb->insert( 
  'wp_profile_hits', 
  array( 
   'vendor_name' => $vendor_slug ,
   'user_ip' => get_client_ip()
   )
  );

} 
this is my function. I just want to get that URL last word and save to data base custom table.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really have time for this now, but in the link I gave you, you'll find the custom vars example and the related filter to properly add the query var.

Comment: see the below the my function..

Answer (score 0):

```
function hitcount(){

global $wpdb;
global $wp_query;

$vendor_slug = $wp_query->query['wcpv_product_vendors'];

$wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_profile_hits', 
    array( 
        **--->>>** 'vendor_name' => $vendor_slug ,
        'user_ip' => get_client_ip()
        )
    );
}
```

This is my function. I just want to add before URL last couple of word and save to custom table in data base.

The Bold line is to be correct. the get the vendor username slug.

Comment: when i use the `$vendor_slug` there is NULL value in output.